# IconItemRenderer with full decorator

Tags: apache-flex, decorator, iconitemrenderer

Recently I have just started working with Flex. I have one problem. Basically, I have the list with IconItemRender decorator. But it is not full.

How do I make it full. Attached is the image difference. The left one is what I have done. The right is the one I wish to do.

http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-6336526-636052/Untitled.png

Edit:

```
    <s:ArrayCollection id="acMainMenu">
        <fx:Object mainMenuLabel="menu 1" icon="data/pics/menu_icon_1.png" decorator="data/pics/menu_side_1.png"/>
        <fx:Object mainMenuLabel="menu 2" icon="data/pics/menu_icon_2.png" decorator="data/pics/menu_side_2.png"/>
        <fx:Object mainMenuLabel="menu 3" icon="data/pics/import_icon.png" decorator="data/pics/menu_side_3.png"/>
        <fx:Object mainMenuLabel="menu 4" icon="data/pics/export_icon.png" decorator="data/pics/menu_side_4.png"/>  
        <fx:Object mainMenuLabel="menu 5" icon="data/pics/menu_icon_5.png" decorator="data/pics/menu_side_5.png"/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group>
    <s:Rect x="0" y="-1" width="774" height="1005">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#D31145" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--[#26ABE4, #F79820, #F65AAE, #C1D832, #FAFA44]-->
<s:List id="mylist" y="-1" width="222" height="668" alternatingItemColors="#FFFFFF"
        change="mylist_changeHandler(event)" color="#424242" contentBackgroundColor="#F5F5F5"
        dataProvider="{acMainMenu}" fontWeight="bold" horizontalCenter="-269" textAlign="start">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer 
                labelField="mainMenuLabel"
                iconField="icon"
                decorator="{data.decorator}"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Comment: @Nick I have already attached the code.

Comment: @user look into the `paddingTop` and related styles.  Also try setting the `verticalGap` to 0.

Comment: @Brian thanks, i have solved it by using `<s:layout><s:VerticalLayout gap="0" variableRowHeight="false" rowHeight="50" horizontalAlign="justify" paddingRight="-10"/></s:layout>`